# In advancing , Did I used it appropiately?

Tags: word-usage

Would you please let me know I have used *in advancing* appropriately in my sentence:

> Here in [my company name], I work closely with two principals which helps me a lot **in advancing** in my career.

thanks.

Comment: *principals which helps?* Apart from that, the use of *advancing* is okay!

Answer (score 0):

> Here in [my company name], I work closely with two principals which helps me a lot in advancing in my career.

Well, if you simply misprinted "**s**" after "**help**" then the rest in fine.

Comment: Advancing my career without in!

Comment: Actually,, Christina is correct. You can _advance a career_ without a preposition. You can also advance _in_ a career, so that’s not ungrammatical, but I prefer it without the extra _in_.

Comment: @J.R. Ahh, yes, actually both are correct. Well let's just say it's not a mistake to omit "**in**".

Comment: @SovereignSun - When you say, “...in advancing my career”, the focus is on the career (promotions, etc.). When you say, “in advancing in my career”, the focus is on the employee. But the difference is so subtle they mean essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> ... in advancing **in** my career.

and

> ...  in advancing my career.

They are both correct.

However, there is another mistake. I do not know what you intended to say, so I will go into the details.

You wrote:

> I work closely with two principals which helps me a lot

which associates "principals (**plural**) with "helps" (3rd person, **singular**) - which is incorrect.

The are two ways to rewrite it, with two **different** meanings.

> 1. I work closely with two principals which help<strike>**s**</strike> me a lot

(notice the strikes "s" - meaning that it should not be used).

In this case, you mean that "the principals help you".

> 2. I work closely with two principals **,** which helps me a lot

(notice the comma after "principals").

In this case, "work closely... helps" a lot.